# How to set different permissions for directories and files using umask and fuse

Tags: fuse, umask

I use `fuse` to mount some directories on Ubuntu. The user should have `rwx` on directories and `rw-` on files.

Now doing this with `setfacl` is quite easy. Doing `setfacl -R -d -m u::rwX,g::rwX,o::--- dir/` does the job perfectly fine.

But how to do this with `umask`?

Answer (score 0):

What you should know about umask first is that umask is a mask; it is not a number to be subtracted.
It turns off permissions that would normally be granted.
Masking is not the same as subtracting, e.g. 666 masked with 001 is still 666 and 666 masked with 003 is 664.
The mask turns off permission bits. If they are already off, the umask makes no change.

Make sure you are in the directory you wanna assign permissions to and do the following:

this link answers exactly what you're looking for!

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

hope this helps.

Comment: You mean `umask u=rwX,g=rwX,o=`? That results in an invalid parameter.

Comment: well I used to use 'umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx'  and it worked fine for me.. Tested on ubuntu all versions

Comment: the full process was using this:
"`sudo setfacl -dR -m u:dev1:rwx,g:www-data:rx,o::rx /directoryName`"   
"`sudo chmod g+w /var/www/DirectoryName/Folder/`"  
"`umask u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`"